# Are these two torques identical?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, vectors, torque, moment

[image: Diagram of forces]

Hello,

I had this question in a MCQ. According to the solution, these torques are indeed identical but I don't understand how.
I tried to decompose $\overrightarrow{AB}$ into $\overrightarrow{AC} + \overrightarrow{CB}$ in order to have the torque $\overrightarrow{M_A}(\overrightarrow{F_2})$ : $\overrightarrow{M_A}(\overrightarrow{F_2}) = \overrightarrow{AB} \cdot \overrightarrow{F_2} = (\overrightarrow{AC} + \overrightarrow{CB}) \cdot \overrightarrow{F_2} = \overrightarrow{AC} \cdot \overrightarrow{F_2} + \overrightarrow{CB} \cdot \overrightarrow{F_2} = \overrightarrow{AC} \cdot \overrightarrow{F_2} + 0 = AC \times F_2$.

On the other hand, I have the torque $\overrightarrow{M_A}(\overrightarrow{F_1})$:
$\overrightarrow{M_A}(\overrightarrow{F_1}) = \overrightarrow{AB} \cdot \overrightarrow{F_1} = AB \times F_1$.

And I'm stuck here, I don't know if it is the right way to do it or not.

Sorry if my question is messy and thanks for the help.

Comment: You should decompose $F_2$ into its components perpendicular and parallel with respect to $AB$, not $AB$ itself

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/168783) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/168783) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think they are.

The perpendicular distance to $\vec{F}_2$ is $h = d \cos \alpha$, and $| \vec{F}_1 | = \cos \alpha | \vec{F}_2 |$

[image: fig1]

So the magnitude of the two torques is

- $ |\vec{M}_A | = d \, | \vec{F}_1 | = d \, (\cos \alpha | \vec{F}_2 |)$
- $ |\vec{M}_A | = h \, | \vec{F}_2 | = (d\,\cos \alpha) | \vec{F}_2 | $